# Multiple Intermittent Errors with Seemingly Simply Graphics Method C#

Tags: c#, colors, picturebox, trackbar

I have a simple method that analyzes a sample image in a pictureBox and increases the value of the Red channel.  Similar other methods analyze other color channels.  The user is given the option of choosing the sample image containing the desired color changes and applying it to their original image.

Everything was working fine until I added a trackBar to enable the user to change how much Red, Green, or Blue they'd like to add to or subtract from their sample image.  Now, everything sometimes works fine on the first run. I was getting a "Cross-thread operation not valid" error, but I seem to have resolved that.  After first run, pictureBox1 often dissapears at random and is replaced by the dreaded red X.  Other times, pictureBox1 has its color changes applied at full power, regardless of the trackBar setting.  Other times, I get an error stating "Object is currently in use elsewhere."  I have, to the best of my understanding of the concept, tried locking the code that errors out, but this has had no effect. I have very thoroughly researched these problems both here and elsewhere, but found no solutions (other than those I have already implemented). Code follows:

EDIT: FWIW, I just got a rare "Object is not set to an instance of an object" error, in regard to int y. I was unable to recreate it. Also, I'm curious, when I'm running multiple methods such as red(), green(), and blue(), is there a preferred way to run them (other than running them from, for example, a pictureBox click)?

**My primary problems** continue to be the intermittent red X in pictureBox1, and the intermittent but frequent "Object is currently in use elsewhere." error. Thank you very much.

```
    private object lockObject = new object();    

    private void red()
    {
            // declare initial variables 
            int xRed = 64;

            // Work around for "Cross-thread operation not valid" error.  This may be a VS issue, not an actual coding error. 
            if (trkColor.InvokeRequired)
                trkColor.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { xRed = trkColor.Value; }));
            else
                xRed = trkColor.Value;

            // Get bitmap from picturebox
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

            lock (lockObject)
            {

            // search through each pixel via x, y coordinates, examine and make changes. Dont let values exceed 255 or fall under 0.  
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int myRed = c.R, myGreen = c.G, myBlue = c.B;
                    myRed += xRed;
                    if (myRed > 255)
                        myRed = 255;
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, myRed, myGreen, myBlue));
                }

            // assign the new bitmap to the picturebox
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)bmp;
            }
    }
```

Comment: "// assign the new bitmap to the picturebox" must be done on UI thread too...

Comment: I'm very new to this and not that familiar with threading.  So...  how would I do this on the UI thread?  Thank you.